# Declare a global class in android

Tags: java, android

I have a main class in my application.
I declared the ftp class at global and when i debug the code,i will get "source not found" error.
If i declare inside the button click event.I wont receive this error.Can anyone tell me how to declare a global class?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
final ftpfunctions ftpclass=new ftpfunctions ();
//code here
Buttonclickevent{
ftpclass.connect();
}
}
```

Even if i declare a api in another class file i also get the same error.

```
public class ftpfunctions extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
 FTPClient ftpClient;
public void connectFTP(){

  try {
      ftpClient= new FTPClient(); 
      ftpClient.connect("myap");
      ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
      ftpClient.login("123", "123");
  } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  }
```

}
    }

Comment: is it crashing? can you post some logs?

Comment: post the complete error

Comment: there is no log. when i click on debug and shows source not found.Edit source lookup path.

Comment: You probably need to declare your 'ftpfunctions' object as 'final' so that it can be accessed inside the callback

Comment: hi i changed to final and still the same error source file not found.
updated my code